# Is there any possibility to disable the screen rotation of the app in jquery-mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Hey guys i'm using phonegap and jquery mobile to build an app for an android phone. Is there any possibility to disable the screen rotation of the app. I am very new to jquery mobile. Sorry if I am asking inappropriate question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible but you must set it in cordova/phonegap parameter not in your app/www

in your app folder there is config.xml

```
<preference name="orientation" value="default" />
<!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do it only using Jquery? Can you think of using Android's Manifest file to fix an orientation for the activity?

Change the following attributes in manifest file:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait" or android:screenOrientation="landscape" in the AndroidManifest.xml:

<activity android:name=".MyActivity"a
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the following code in your 'config.xml'

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
```

or

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
```